# Can't install updates after upgrading to Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, troubleshooting, upgrade

I have just upgraded to Snow Leopard over a Leopard install.

After the reboot I get a notification that new updates are available. I click "Install and restart", I get a license text, I click "Agree" but nothing happens. Nothing gets installed.

If I open the Console, the messages I see right after I click "Agree" are below, but I think the problem is related to the first message.

```
25/09/09 09:35:42   com.apple.SecurityServer[24]    Engine::authorize: Rule::evaluate returned 4294907288 returning errAuthorizationInternal
25/09/09 09:35:42   GrowlHelperApp[318] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x3518f0 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
25/09/09 09:35:42   GrowlHelperApp[318] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x351d70 of class NSCFDictionary autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
25/09/09 09:35:42   GrowlHelperApp[318] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x16c250 of class NSCFArray autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
```

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Legal copy of snow leopard correct? Sorry but in today's world it needs to be asked as one can not assume anymore.

Comment: Yes, it is a legal copy.

Comment: How is the legality of the Snow Leopard install relevant? How would Snow Leopard even know if it an illegal version?

Comment: @joshhunt: Copies of OS X that have been modified to run on non-Apple hardware ("Hackintoshes") often have trouble getting and installing new updates. I think that's what Tony was referring to.

Comment: My copy is legal and running on a MacBook, not a hackintosh.

Answer (score 2):

Just found the solution on [this forum thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-774615.html).

1. In Finder, go to your home folder (the one with the house icon next to it in the sidebar)
2. Select navigate to `Library` > `Preferences` > `byHost`
3. Delete all files inside
4. Restart your computer.

Or, from Terminal, run

```
rm ~/Library/Preferences/byHost/*
```

Answer (score 0):

My sister had the same problem she had to re-install Snow Leopard and that solved the problem (might be a little extreme)

Comment: Re-install would be my last option. :)

Comment: Yeah i would of guessed so lol, a couple of people i know experienced the same problem and are still waiting for apple tech support